# Django error showing none type when it isn't none when calling a function

Tags: python, django

can any one explain why the following error occurs
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_data'

the error occurs  when i tried to call "passdata = self.check_data(request)" method
can any one explain why it occurs were iam going wrong

class UpdateRepo:

```
def update_marks(self,request):
    passdata = self.check_data(request)
    get_values = Marks.objects.filter(id=request.data['id'])
    if get_values.exists():
        thr = get_values.update(
            English = passdata[0],
            Tamil = passdata[1],
            Maths = passdata[2]
        )
    return thr


def check_data(self,request):
    if int(request.data['English']) >50:
        English = request.data['English']
    else:
        English = constants.Marks['English']
    if int(request.data['Tamil']) >50:
        Tamil = request.data['Tamil']
    else:
        Tamil = constants.Marks['Tamil']
    if int(request.data['Maths']) >50:
        Maths = request.data['Maths']
    else:
        Maths = constants.Marks['Maths']
    return [English,Tamil,Maths]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you haven't created an instance for your class. for example, if your method belong to class "Something". then add:

```
abc = Something()
abc.update_marks(request)
```

Comment: Thank you very much i created instance wrongly that shows the error now its working